# Is there some way to include the folder name in a Netbeans template?

Tags: templates, netbeans

I am working on a fairly large project in Netbeans written in PHP. The folders in ./modules/ share their name with the namespace used in the file. Actually, for easy auto-include the namespace is identical to the directory structure.

How should I format my template so that it picks up the folder name and uses it in the namespace declaration?